# How to work with Error boundaries in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm trying to add error boundaries for a simple application.When I click a button "Something went wrong" should be displayed in the screen.But in my case it is not displaying like that.As I understand `ErrorBoundary.js` is not working since I tried console log it.When I run this application in the screen it shows **Error: Not a correct click**

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Button from './Components/Button';
import ErrorBoundary from './Components/ErrorBoundary';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
        <ErrorBoundary>
        <Button />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log("Test Button")
        this.state = { error: true};
        throw new Error('Not a correct click');
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            return <h1>Caught an error!</h1>
        }
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick} style={{ color: 'white', background: 'blue', width: 200, height: 50 }}>Throw Error</button>
    }
}

export default Button;
```

**ErrorBoundary.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {

    constructor (props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hasError: false,
            error: null,
            info: null
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error){
        this.state.hasError = true
    }

    componentDidCatch (error,info){
        console.log(error);
        console.log(info)
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.hasError){
            return <h2>Something went wrong</h2>
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks correct but according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html):

Error boundaries do not catch errors for:

- Event handlers ([learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers))
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

In my experience error boundaries catch errors in render() and stop it propagating outside of the boundary.

The intention behind error boundaries is to avoid half-broken React render state.

It is recommended to use `try/catch` to catch errors in event handlers.

Moving `throw` to `Button.render` should help ErrorBoundary to catch the error in your example:

```
handleClick() {
    console.log("Test Button")
    this.state = { error: true};
    // throw new Error('Not a correct click');
}

render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
        throw new Error('Not a correct click')
        return <h1>Caught an error!</h1>
    }
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick} style={{ color: 'white', background: 'blue', width: 200, height: 50 }}>Throw Error</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly throwing error from button click doesn't trigger error boundary.
You can make use of useState, useEffect, button to trigger the error boundary on button click.

```
const [flag, setflag] = useState(false);
    
useEffect(() => {
   if (flag) throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
}, [flag]);
    
render(){
  return <button onClick={()=>setFlag(!flag)} />
}
```